# Execute cmd command on windows server with web app

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, iis-7

I have a web app c # hosted on IIS on a computer with windows server 2008, I ran a command on a windows server cmd through C#, but it doesn't work, I tried it locally on my computer and the command works, I don't know why it doesn't work on the computer with windows server, I use this source code,I put a log but doesn't throw any error.

```html
        protected void btnReboot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                //StartShutDown("-l");
                StartShutDown("-f -r -t 5");

                Log2("MNS OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log2("MNS ERROR  " + ex.ToString());
            }

        }
        private static void StartShutDown(string param)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
            proc.FileName = "cmd";
            proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.Arguments = "/C shutdown " + param;
            Process.Start(proc);
        }
```

Comment: Change /C in /K and comment out the line _proc.WindowStyle_ Now you should be able to see the console windows opened by the command and you can look if there is an error message

Comment: @Steve  It doesn't open any command window

Comment: Did you comment out the line the hides the command window?

Comment: And are you able to log on your server and try to open a command window using same account used to launch the Process?

Comment: @Steve  on the server if it is possible to open the command window manually and I comment out the line proc.WindowStyle

Comment: @Steve there is basically no way to do that - IIS normally runs under headless account... (also all this sort of purely entertainment - normally account IIS runs under will not have permissions to shutdown... or even launch process if using user's impersonation)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov So it isn't possible to reboot the server with my application?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually capture the error output from the process that was launched by [redirecting the standard error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror?view=netframework-4.8). An example would be like this:

```cs
private static void StartShutDown(string param)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; // You need to set this
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 

    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C shutdown " + param;
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.Start();

    string stdoutx = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();         
    string stderrx = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // here is where you get the error output string        
    p.WaitForExit();

    Console.WriteLine("Exit code : {0}", p.ExitCode);
    Console.WriteLine("Stdout : {0}", stdoutx);
    Console.WriteLine("Stderr : {0}", stderrx);
}
```

Once you have the Stderr you can check its contents and, if it's not empty then you know an error occurred.

Comment: On the Stderr line it shows me access denied